# Splitting up same values in a query output

Tags: sql, sorting

For starters I should say that I'm using openoffice.

I've got a query with the following columns.

[image: Sample]

Now when I get the results there are multiple delegations with the same value.
Let's just say for demonstrating purposes I got 6 delegations which are and 3 of them have the same value. In the results they are shown directly below one another. But for this I need a result where I can't have that. I need to separate each value in a way that they don't appear after each other.

So that the results shouldn't look like this

[image: Results now]

but that the delegations are separated with a least another delegation in between

I hope you got what I want to do.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and tag the database you are using.

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

you use a following query

```
query=SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
    FROM table_name;
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.
nside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.